# authorities Collection from Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt) is empty

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth, jwt

I am testing a method that override some parameter in jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter but always when i debug get that this collection (Collection authorities = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt);)  is empty did not know the reason  !! here is my code

can some one help me please .. Thank you!

```
class SecurityConfigTest {

@Test
void convertWithOverriddenGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() {

    Jwt jwt = this.jwt(Collections.singletonMap("scope", "message:read message:write"));
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt);

    assertThat(authorities).containsExactly(
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority("message:read"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority("message:write"));
    Assert.assertTrue(authorities.contains("roles"));
}
private Jwt jwt(Map<String, Object> claims) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("alg", JwsAlgorithms.RS256);
    return new Jwt("token", Instant.now(), Instant.now().plusSeconds(3600), headers, claims);
}
```

}

Comment: remove `jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");` line

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes it worked with this solution thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the docs the default claim that spring will use when trying to find Authorities to mapping scopes to roles is the `scope` claim in the JWT.

You can override this behavior by supplying a custom `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` and use the `setAuthoritiesClaimName` to set a different claim.

the above code has this line

```
jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
```

so spring tries to find a claim called `roles` in the JWT, that it can map to authorities and it can't find it, so it returns empty.

Removing that line will fix the problem.